# Gap between border-image after using transform: rotate

Tags: css, css-transforms

I am trying to create a box with a jagged edge, that can actually be used as a HTML element should be, and can resize etc.

Finally got my head around border-image, got it looking nice, and then when I rotate it, it gets a gap between the border-image and the main fill:

[image: The Problem]

I googled it, and found an answer on SO telling someone to set

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

This cleared it up, but obviously only in webkit browsers.

I tried using `-moz-backface-visibility` as well, but it didn't clear the issue up in Firefox.

Any suggestions?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tomxpand/YrDvL/)

e: I actually thought I may be able to fix it by setting a background color, and then setting the `background-clip` to `padding-box`, but honestly it just left me in the same position.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One trick that fixes the problem  both in  Webkit and FF is setting perspective (instead of backface visibility)

```
.box.one {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(999px) rotate(1deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(1deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(1deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(1deg);
    transform: perspective(999px) rotate(1deg);
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wkk7W/7/)

Comment: amazing, this is exactly what I needed. I was hoping there would be a trick that 'just made it work'.

Answer (score 1):

Adding an after pseudo class with negative margin seems to fix the Firefox issue.

```
.rough:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    margin: -1px;
    height: 302px;
    background: black;
}
```

Fiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Wkk7W/3/

Note that the display:block seems to be an essential part of my hack/fix.

**Update:** Depending on your plans for content *inside* the div, that exact example might not suit.  However, I think the concept could be tweaked depending on your requirements - e.g. using a 3px wide black border instead of a background fill, and using position:absolute to allow other text to be layered on top of the box.

Comment: Nice! Not perfect for my needs, but I'm messing about with this now, made a few different solutions using this as a base, but none perfect for my needs yet.
And I think the `display:block` being essential is just because of the width not being set on a pseudo element, if i set the element to relative, pseudo to absolute and `width:100%` then it doesn't require `display:block`

Comment: Got it working with content and fluid height, just cant get fluid width perfect, but it covers my needs.

If I don't get a better response in a few hours i'll mark this as the answer, heres me fiddle for content: http://jsfiddle.net/Wkk7W/5/

Answer (score 1):

Gonna answer myself, because this solution actually covers my needs of it being "as a html element should be, and can resize etc", even though I developed this solution from Grants answer.

http://jsfiddle.net/Wkk7W/6/

Set the element to `position:absolute`, then give it a pseudo element with:

```
content: "";
display: block;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
width: 102%;
margin: -1px 0 0 -1%;
height: 102%;
background: black;
z-index: -1;
```

This way it keeps the elements width and height, z-index: -1 to put it behind the text. It might not require the display:block, i didn't check.

There are still a few tiny gaps but they are basically impossible to cover and I am happy with it the way it is.